# Selecting randomly from a drop down list?

Tags: watin

The issue here is with multiple drop downs on a single page. Say, I had dropdown1 with values A, B, C, D, E, F and G.  Then I had dropdown2 with options 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  Would it be possible to have Watin look at the possible values for that drop down and select one at random?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example - you have to customize it for your purposes but you'll get the general idea:

```
IE browser = new IE(@"http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/demo_dropdownlist.aspx");
var options = browser.SelectList("drop1").Options;
Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.Next(options.Count);
browser.SelectList("drop1").Select(options[index].ToString());
```